# Connect the Raspebrry pi to WiFi from another device

Tags: python, wifi, connection, networkmanager

Is there anyway to connect the raspberry pi to WiFi from another device like from a flask app?
I know it's a crazy idea, without connecting to a network I cannot access flask app but I'm just wondering if we can create a WiFi access point then access the pi from another device and connect to a local network. I'm looking for something like [this.](https://github.com/balena-io/wifi-connect)

My goal is to control robot using virtual joystick from app or a browser. If I set an access point can I still connect to Pi using remote desktop connection over Wifi? I don't have a monitor right now

*Machine: Raspberry pi 3 model B+*

**Example (Balena wifi-connect):**
[image]

Comment: Why crazy? It's interesting. At first, you need to make an AP, configure the raspberry pi with Apache or Nginx then show the input page (splash page/captive portal) to the user to input SSID and password of that. After that, the user hits the SET button, the values will send to raspberry pi and it get the value then disable AP. Finally, try to connect to that SSID. There is a lot of challenges here that I see you would face. However, short answer, YES, you can.

Comment: @M.Rostami, sorry but : `to the user to input SSID and password of that` , I'm not really sure it is necessary with a real captive portal. This can be done directly by the device Wi-Fi menu.

Comment: @Ephemeral :-) , The SSID and Password of SAM AP on the picture that raspberry pi would be connected.

Comment: @M.Rostami, Oh sorry , yes :)

Comment: @Ephemeral At first, thank you for the precision. Honestly, it's not for connecting the phone to an AP. The phone will connect to the raspberry pi AP, then it will connect raspberry pi to connect to another AP (look at SAM AP) by phone's splash page.

Comment: @M.Rostami, Yes indeed I was stuck on the first stage.

Comment: @M. Rostami Thanks, I will try it.I hope it will work. But what if it's a Flask app accessed through phone's browser? I have apache2 already installed and configured for Flask. Can I retrieve a splash screen from flask app by connecting to Pi access point?

Comment: @Ephemeral I'm working on a small robot and I don't want a display on it. I want to access the robot control app(Flask app) from phone's browser or a hybrid app.

Comment: @smc "*Can I retrieve a splash screen from flask app by connecting to Pi access point?*" -- I have not done something like it by Flask. In addition, the splash page has some limitations on different devices. It's a process of the phone's captive portal and depends on the manufacturer. However, I think it will work like a charm. Please test that and inform the result here. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59643642/6602159) out. It's an apache captive portal implementation.

Comment: @smc, Just create an access point and web service on your raspberry-pi (server) and write an application for your phone (client) where you send your robot command to the access point and the web server ? You can use bluetooth also ...What is your goal ? robot control ? IOT control/datas logs ?

Comment: @Ephemeral My goal is to control robot using virtual joystick from app or a browser. If I set an access point can I still connect to Pi using remote desktop connection over Wifi? I don't have a monitor right now.

Comment: @smc, yes you can with VNCserver (RPi) and VNCViewer (on your phone). But you can have just a server (TCP/UDP) on the RPi or simply use SSH for example with your own bash script.